# Connect To single user mode SQL Server But Get Error Account Is Disabled -

Tags: sql-server, admin, sqlcmd

My SQL Server start with `-m;` parameter and I login with Local Admin with user Administrator and in cmd I run command

```
sqlcmd -S .\servername -E
```

but I get error:

> login failed for user pc-name\administrator . Reason : the account is disabled.

Which account is disabled ? sql sa user or administrator?
when connect with local admin on single user mode used sa user?

Edited : I Found Problem because  NT AUTHRITY\SYSTEM is disabled on Sql .
Now My Question Is : How To Enable NT AUTHRITY User On Single User mode .
And I not have sa password but can login with local admin.
and I do not want to reset sa password because some app use db and and connect with sa.

Comment: So whats your question? The error message is clear...

Comment: i sure some app used sa to connect to database and so sa not disabled . i cant access to sa password. i will use single mode to add new user to database

Comment: @MostafaBagheri Have you seen [Reset SQL Server sa password](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61825/reset-sql-server-sa-password)?

Comment: When starting SQL Server in single-user mode you need to make sure all other SQL-related services are stopped, especially SQL Server Agent, otherwise they'll consume the one and only connection that's available.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning  Yes All serices Are Stop . only Sql Instance Service is Start

Comment: Try using `-mSQLCMD` instead of just `-m` when starting SQL Server in single user mode, this will prevent any applications that don't identify themselves as SQLCMD from connecting. Have a read through [Connect to SQL Server when system administrators are locked out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out) for more information.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I Use -mSQLCMD -S .\servername -E but get error   : -mSQLCMD  is not recognized..... I Used Correct ?

Comment: also i add -mSQLCMD; to server parameter and  run -sqlcmd -S .\servername -E  bug get error  the account is disabled ...

Comment: my windows is 7 32 bit sp1 , when start sql management studio the app not responding i test many version but all version have problem . !!!

Comment: from documentation:  use  `sqlcmd -U MyLogin -S <ComputerName>\<InstanceName>` to have the server request login info

Comment: i found problem . NT AUTHRITY\SYSTEM  is disabled . because of this i get error. now how to enable NT AUTHRITY\SYSTEM  from user single mode